JetBrains IDE Has Issue With Gaining Focus
When I'm using any JetBrains IDE on Linux (GNOME on Wayland) and I go to another window like a web browser or terminal and I then refocus on the IDE, the IDE doesn't gain focus on the cursor and I still am typing in the other window. What may be the problem and are there any solutions?

The issue is not reproduced on the default Ubuntu+Gnome on Wayland configuration, and it is probably caused by gnome-tweaks or some other custom settings.
Generic workaround
Try native Wayland mode (Add -Dawt.toolkit.name=WLToolkit to "Help | Edit custom VM options" and restart)
